# chartist.js pie chart with labels AND percentage on the pie

Tags: chartist.js

I want to create a pie chart with chartist.js with labels (which are shown in the legend) AND also with percentages in the pie itself.

This is the pie chart. I want to add percentage values to the pieces. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiIKb.png

Here (https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html) is an example with percentages in the pie. But this only works if I do NOT add labels.

Adding labels to the data (e.g. labels: ['Dog','Cat','Cow','Snake',],) results in "NaN%" display.

I want to see the percentages in the pie itself and also put labels (for the legend) into the data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must keep an **array containing your labels**, and use the `labelInterpolationFnc` with two parameters to get index, and use it to get the proper label with percentage:

```js
var animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cow', 'Snake'];

var data = {
  series: [5, 3, 4]
};

var sum = function(a, b) {
  return a + b
};

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', data, {
  labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, idx) {
    var percentage = Math.round(value / data.series.reduce(sum) * 100) + '%';
    return animals[idx] + ' ' + percentage;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
```

Note that we must not use the `labels` in your data array (only the series), otherwise the value parameter in `labelInterpolationFnc` will be filled with the label instead of the value, so we couldn't calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

what you would need to do ist to produce the label on your own.
You need to produce a string like [Labeltext] + ' | ' + [Share]

In my case I created a variable which holds the total sum of all pie elements... called [griall]....

Then there is this function which calculates shares...

```js
  function calcProz(value, griall) {
   return Math.round(value / griall * 100) + '%';
  };
```

later on when I generate the Array which holds the labels I use this function to add the percentages to the text...

```js
  chartlabels[i]=dbresult[i].use + ' | ' + calcProz(dbresult[i].gri,griall);
```

where dbresult[i].use is the initial label text and dbresult[i].gri is the value which is going to the chart (both coming from a database)

after all when defining the chart you just add the labels...

```js
var data = {
    series: chartdata,
  //  series: [25,16,15, 14, 4,2,1]
    labels: chartlabels
  
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and you answer. I am not sure that we understand each other correctly. I already have the percentages computed. What I  want is to display the percentages DIRECTLY  the pie chart itself and the labels(texts) in the legend. I tried your solution but it results in having the percentages in the legend, too. Was this your intention?

Comment: In this case I assume it will not be your solution. My solution simply does the percentages behind the labeltext... (As you see - there are some lable placement issues here). 

just like this: https://sectorbyte.de/owncloud/index.php/s/QvHmoCXoLj6laTz

Comment: I think what might be the solution here is drawing the percentages as label and place them wherever you like. And add a separate legend underneath or beside the chart. There is a proof of concept if you follow this link...

https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/21

I

Comment: Thank you for the link to the issues at chartist. This is exactly my topic.